# Jmeter http post sampler syntax

Tags: testing, jmeter, http-post

I'm triyng to test a rest api using jmeter script. When I launch the test, I get the following exception:

```
{"timestamp" : 1463775753585,
"status" : 400,
"error" : "Bad Request",
"exception" : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message" : "Could not read JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.tutos.example.models.Product[\"category\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.tutos.example.models.Product[\"category\"])",
"path" : "/product"
}
```

Here is my data of post:

```
{"code":${productCode}, "intitule":"${productName}", "cost":"${cost}", "category":{"id":"${categoryId}"}}
```

But when I remove the property category, everything is OK.

What am I missing please ?

Comment: obviously it's not happy with your input, you should really ask the developers of the application you are testing

Comment: This may be a case  when there are UTF8 characters in the request and the server can't handle them . This is an assumption as you have not shared the input data.

Comment: please, what can I do then?

Comment: @Coccoonx  please check the json you are providing to the server is not happy with it . this is not proper json request . you are saying it is happy when you take out "category" that means here jmeter has nothing to do with, Kindly ask your developer what is the proper input json for this reuqest send to be . FYI use online tool http://jsonpath.com/  check json validity that you send through jemeter. Hope this helps